# Storing Kafka Avro serialzed data to parquet file using Spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, parquet

I am creating Kafka and spark streaming pipeline. Here data is avro serialized using AVRO GenericRecord and Kafka schema registry then stored in a Kafka topic. Spark streaming is used to read from Kafka topic. My requirement is to store spark streaming output into parquet file in appending manner using java API. Please let me know suitable approach.